# How to integrate an App Secret into your Adjust SDK?

Tags: android, adjust-android

According to the document of AdjustSDK. This is code to integrate

```
config.setAppSecret(secretId, info1, info2, info3, info4);
```

Please explain me the parameters inside it.

Answer (score 1):

An App Secret is a set of five integers. Adjust uses this value to hash key data points when sending SDK traffic to Adjust’s servers, where Adjust can verify the legitimacy of the installs based on this hash value. The App Secret is so instrumental in computing the SDK Signature that only the plain text format (as exported from your Adjust Dashboard) can be used to derive it.

[9.2 What is an App Secret?](https://docs.adjust.com/en/sdk-signature/)

Comment: Thanks. Set of five integers including secredId, info1, info2, info3, info4, info5?. And is it created when we create App secred on Adjust's server?

Comment: Yes, set of five integers including the parameters and they create in your Adjust Dashboard.

Comment: So how do you know it has been integrated? How to test it?